# BASH: html2text from a string variable not from a file

Tags: bash

I have a html code that is stored in a string var, and I like to use html2text to convert it to a string of text. I could save it in a file, and read it from there, but I wonder if its not possible to trick html2text out somehow to read from the variable and not expect a file.

The man of html2text say:

> html2text reads HTML documents from the input-urls, formats each of
>   them into a stream of plain text characters, and writes the result  to
>   standard output (or into output-file, if the -o command line option is
>   used).
>
> If  no  input-urls are specified on the command line, html2text reads
>   from standard input. A dash as the input-url is an alternate way to
>   specify standard input.

but for some reason I am not able to pipe it into it.
It always brings out a blank result

```
mail_text=`html2text <<< "$mail_html"`
```

also blank result for $mail_text

then I tried on the shell

```
str_text=`cat /usr/src/files/str_html`; html2text <<< "$str_text"
```

and the out put was the correct text. But for some reason the first 2 raws are blank.

Comment: ok, try running `html2text` w/o argument. If you get prompted to type something (like what happens if you run `cat` w/o argument), that means it can read from STDIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
html2text <<< "$string"
```

`<<<` is a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *here-string*

If you want to store the output in a variable :

```
output="$(html2text <<< "$string")"
echo "$output"
```

Comment: and how do I collect the output ?

Comment: It returns a blanck result

Comment: The string should be valid HTML. What is your HTML string ?

Comment: strange is that on the shell its working, but in the script reads only the first row, thats blank